# undefined reference to...while make install in ubuntu 12.04LTS precise

Tags: linker

```
tony@tony-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$ cd '/home/tony/Desktop/run-privexec' 
tony@tony-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/run-privexec$ make install
mkdir -p build build/obj
gcc -lcap -lecryptfs build/obj/main.o build/obj/privexec.o build/obj/utils.o build/obj/perms.o -o build/privexec
build/obj/privexec.o: In function `insert_key':
privexec.c:(.text+0x7df): undefined reference to `ecryptfs_add_passphrase_key_to_keyring'
build/obj/privexec.o: In function `remove_key':
privexec.c:(.text+0xdcb): undefined reference to `ecryptfs_remove_auth_tok_from_keyring'
build/obj/perms.o: In function `drop_privileges':
perms.c:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `cap_get_proc'
perms.c:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `cap_set_flag'
perms.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `cap_set_proc'
perms.c:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `cap_free'
build/obj/perms.o: In function `raise_privileges':
perms.c:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `cap_get_proc'
perms.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `cap_set_flag'
perms.c:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `cap_set_proc'
perms.c:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `cap_free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [privexec] Error 1
```

Comment: Seems you're not finding some functions.  Show more code so we can actually see what you are trying to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linker order - GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

Answer (score 2):

Your `Makefile` produces this command:

```
gcc -lcap -lecryptfs build/obj/main.o ...
```

which is incorrect. It should be:

```
gcc build/obj/main.o ... -lcap -lecryptfs
```

The order of object files and libraries on the link line matters. You can read [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) or [here](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) to understand why it does.